# Humanizing sentence when using pluralize in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, pluralize

What is the best way to define is/are in a sentence that uses the Django template pluralize filter?
For example:

```
<p>
    Your item{{ items|length|pluralize }}
    is/are
    currently being processed and will ship soon.
</p>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As shown in last example of [`pluralize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#pluralize), you can try

```
Your item{{ items|length|pluralize:" is,s are" }}
currently being processed and will ship soon.
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`pluralize`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize) with alternative suffix argument.

```
<p>
    Your item{{ items|length|pluralize }}
    {{ items|length|pluralize:"is,are" }}
    currently being processed and will ship soon.
</p>
```